# vue-material form POST set

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-material

I would like to make a login page with [vue-material](http://vuematerial.io/). I have the form base from [here](https://codepen.io/vue-material/pen/MJVgEz). I'm using laravel 5.4 on the server side.

My template:

```
<div id="app">
  <md-layout md-tag="form" novalidate @submit.stop.prevent="submit" md-align="center">
    <md-layout md-tag="md-card" md-column md-flex="30" md-flex-medium="40" md-flex-small="60" md-flex-xsmall="90" class="md-primary">
      <md-card-header>
        <div class="md-title">Login</div>
      </md-card-header>

      <md-card-content>
        <md-input-container>
          <md-icon>person</md-icon>
          <label>Email</label>
          <md-input email required v-model="email" />
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container md-has-password>
          <md-icon>lock</md-icon>
          <label>Password</label>
          <md-input type="password" required v-model="password" />
        </md-input-container>
      </md-card-content>

      <md-card-actions>
        <md-button type="submit">Login</md-button>
      </md-card-actions>
    </md-layout>
  </md-layout>
</div>
```

My questions:

1. How can I set that the form use POST and not GET?
2. How can I set that input fields values should be sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the request from a GET to a POST, add a `method` attribute to the `md-layout` tag that being rendered as the form:

```
<md-layout 
  md-tag="form" 
  method="POST" 
  novalidate 
  @submit.stop.prevent="submit" 
  md-align="center" 
>
```

Then, to send the values of the input fields in the POST, add `name` attributes to the inputs:

```
<md-input email required v-model="email" name="email" />
```

And,

```
<md-input type="password" required v-model="password" name="password" />
```

---

[Here's a working codepen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjyBRe)

Comment: Thank you! :) Its working. I have to solve the TokenMismatchException. Can you help ?

Comment: I have all vue-material elements imported, but if i use that md-layout i receive
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <md-layout>